# Session service: BundleConfigurationLoader can't find preview_dao_bundle.xml

Tags: content-delivery

I'm trying to get my session-enabled content service working. In the logs I see that the constructor of `com.sdl.web.content.odata.query.service.QueryServiceImpl` throws an exception with the following nested exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bundleConfigurationLoader': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Can't find configuration file: [ preview_dao_bundle.xml ]

It seems reasonable to me that it should be trying to find this, as it's configured under Storages as

```
<StorageBindings>
    <Bundle src="preview_dao_bundle.xml"/>
</StorageBindings>
```

There's no such xml file to be seen on the file system, but that doesn't worry me unduly, as IIRC, these bundle configs are typically embedded in the relevant jar file. This leaves me wondering whether there's a specific jar file that I should be checking, or if it's possible my classpath is messed up. What should I be looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cd_session jar file was in the correct location when compared with the relative location in the SDL Web 8.5 release zip. The problem seems to have been with the class path. The class path is set up by the script which installs the service. As I had done an "xcopy" upgrade, the files were in the correct places but the values in the registry hadn't been updated. Uninstalling and re-installing the service seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks to Shiva for identifying the jar, which enabled me to check that it was in the expected location. Thanks also to Rai and Nuno for nudging me in the direction of the class path.

Answer (score 4):

The "preview_doa_bundle.xml" is embedded in the **cd_session.jar** and the "cd_webservice_preview_cartrige.xml" is embedded in the **cd_preview_ambient.jar**.

We would NOT find an explicit configuration in our /config/ folder. Do you have the jars mentioned above in your bin location?

Answer (score 0):

We are facing similar issue with our web 8.5 upgrade.
while webapp on Dev environment working fine with 8.5 stage throwing below error in our core log.

> Could not find publication url
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'bundleConfigurationLoader': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'configurationLoader'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'storageResourceConfigurationLoaderImpl': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>   2018-12-13 21:54:45,443 ERROR GetResourceBundleTag - Could not load
>   localization context for page [tcm:76-1684-64] 2018-12-13 21:54:45,544
>   ERROR GetResourceBundleTag - Could not load localization context for
>   page [tcm:76-1684-64]

Comment: Hi Krishna and welcome to Tridion StackExchange. Please feel free and create a separate question. This question is already closed and your 'answer' is not an answer to this question.

Comment: We found 2 jars which are actually causing this issue and these Jars had no dependency with our code.

Just deleted them and that resolved our issue.

Comment: @krishnagarikapati - Could you please add the details of the two JAR files that you deleted (and anything else you needed to do) to your answer so that it's more helpful for others in the future?